# Need to get expiry alert for Azure blob storage SAS token

Tags: azure, storage, azure-keyvault, azure-automation, sas-token

We are having Azure Storage Container & generated the SAS token for the production usage. We need to get the SAS token expiry alert for the same.

I have tried below steps,

1. Stored the SAS token to Azure Keyvault
2. Got the expiry date for the SAS token using automation account runbook powershell command.

Next need to configure email alert before 7 days for the SAS token expiry date.

Comment: so your question is about sending email not about expiry date ?

Comment: Yes Thomas. Need a email notification.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment for test email notification it's work fine***

To send email Notification you have grant **`Mail.Send`**  **Application permission** and **grant Admin consent** like below:

[image]

After granting permission I can send email notification using below cmdlet:

[image]

```perl
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId 'clientID' -TenantId 'tenantID' -CertificateThumbprint 'certthumbprint'
    
    $message = @{
        subject = 'test'
        ToRecipients = @(
                @{
                    EmailAddress = @{
                        Address = "email@email.com"
                    }
                }
            )
        body = @{
            contentType = 'html'
            content = 'hello'
        }
    }
    
    Send-MgUserMail -UserId 'upn_of_user_running_script' -Message $message
```

Comment: Hello Imran,  Thanks for your reply. I need to know the SAS expiry notification. How can i configure? Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Imran, I need to notify the Storage Blob SAS token expiry. You send the document for Keyvault expert alert.